# Do I use a dash or a semicolon here, or something else entirely?

Tags: sentence, semicolons, dashes

Is it

"In other words, you can compare my existence in the dating world with living in the Sahara--bone dry with the occasional oasis appearing"

or

"In other words, you can compare my existence in the dating world with living in the Sahara; it is bone dry with the occasional oasis appearing"

Thanks!

Comment: Most U.S. publishers use a closed-up em dash (—) rather than a double hyphen (--) for "dash" punctuation; some British publishers prefer to use an en dash with letter spaces on each side ( – ), I believe. The punctuation choice between dash and semicolon is a matter of personal preference. In my view, the example that you ask about reads better with the dash than with the semicolon, but other readers and writers will bring their own punctuation preferences to the question.

Comment: You could also use a colon (personally, I might actually prefer that to a dash) or turn it into two sentences. We can't tell you what you *should* use.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a dash instead of a semicolon indicating that the latter part of your sentence is the meaning or an accurate description of what you've mentioned in the former part without having an actual pause as a semicolon indicates a short pause which is not necessary in your sentence.

"In other words, you can compare my existence in the dating world with living in the Sahara ~bone dry with the occasional oasis appearing" :)